# Error: Unable to initialize main class tinder.ServerApp Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After running `java -jar tinder-app-final.jar`:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class tinder.ServerApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler
```

I am trying to deploy a Java Servlet app to AWS (EC2). Here in putty console (Amazon Linux 2 AMI) I'm getting this error:

[image]

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependencies>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.49.v20220914</version>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.49.v20220914</version>
        </dependency>
        // Other required dependencies...
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>tinder.ServerApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>tinder-app-final</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: would be so funny if Tinder (the app) was run like this.

Comment: it`s just deployment part :)